# Install iPhone App in iPad iOS 11

Tags: ipad, app-store, ios11

In My iPad I am using iPhone mode apps but today I have updated my iPad to iOS 11 after that there is no option to install the iPhone mode apps. In the search tab there is a filter option but it is not enabling. I don't the exact reason. Also I don't know whether from iOS 11 Apple is restricting this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just off the phone with Apple Care:  Try typing in your search, then hit search, and then you will be able to click on "filter" to search for the app.  If that doesn't work, go to your phone, open the app, search for the app in the store and on the top right there is a blue dot with 3 small white dots.  Click on that and air drop it to your iPad.  Hope this helps, it helped me.

Comment: I tried by Swifth off the iPad and searched the app but nothing works. Sorry I don't have iPhone, I have only iPad

Answer (score 0):

1. Search one application and click on that application.
2. you can see filter option on left top corner.
3. click on filter.
4. you can see various options. now select support options.

[image: select support]

5. you can see 2 options iPad and iPhone Only.

[image: select appropriate options]

Comment: For me Filter button is disabled. I couldn't select that.

Comment: search any app and click on that app then after also filter button disabled ?

Comment: My searching App is only for iPhone. So my App is not listing and I couldn't change the Option

Comment: if you search for any other apps then it will enabled the filter button ?